# How to display video controls while the video is seeking ? (mediaelement.js)

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, mediaelement.js, hls.js

I am using MediaElement.js with the following default settings

```
{...,
alwaysShowControls : false, 
hideVideoControlsOnLoad : false,
hideVideoControlsOnPause : false
}
```

Is there a way to show controls and the seek bar while the video is seeking (the loading indicator is being shown)?

Should i use the seeking & seeked events in order to show/hide controls and if so how to manually do it and reset it to atohide?